# What does @Html.Sitecore.Placeholder() point to?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

In Sitecore 7 MVC, my understanding is that partial views are represented by using Razor declarations such as `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("some_thing")` in a `.cshtml` file.

In this context, what does the argument `"some_thing"` actually represent - is it something located in the Sitecore instance?  If so, how can I locate the thing that `"some_thing"` represents within the Sitecore database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("some_thing")` is typically used in a layout page such as your DefaultLayout page.

Like Marek said it is a place that you put components in a position top/bottom.

If you log into Sitecore and look into at a page, under the Presentation tab, there is an icon that says Detail. Click that. A pop-up will open (I think it still did in version 7, I dodn't have an instance running. On that popup, select a component or add a new component to the Default Layout.

In the settings for the component will be a field called Placeholder.  Put the text "some_thing" in there without the quotes.

I think this is what you are asking what this is the placeholder representing.

Comment: Got it - so it points to a component's presentation details.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In the shortest way: `Sitecore Placeholder` is a place where you can add your components.

The argument `some_thing` in `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("some_thing")` is the name of the placeholder.

You can have multiple placeholders on your page. When you add a component to a page, you tell Sitecore "Put in in placeholder `some_thing` and that's how Sitecore knows where to place it.

Read [Presentation Component Reference](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/presentation_component_reference-a4.pdf) for more information (yeah this document is years old, but the idea is still the same).

Comment: Thanks Marek - finding the appropriate SDN documentation for this was very tough.  The other part of my question is, if `"some_thing"` references an MVC view (I think the Sitecore terminology is "view rendering"?), then where can I figure out how this mapping is defined?  (Or is this simply by convention?  Does `"some_thing"` always map onto a `some_thing.cshtml` file?)

Comment: No. `some_thing` in your case is a name of the placeholder (as I wrote above). It has nothing to do with any rendering. If you have any component (no matter if it is view rendering, controller rendering or any other component type), you can place it inside placeholder. Name of the placeholder allows Sitecore to place renderings in correct places on the page.